# Applying a formula to list of pandas dfs, getting error 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec.array([(202101L, 100.0, nan), (202102L, 110.0, nan), (202103L, 115.0, nan),
 (202104L, 118.0, nan), (202105L, 123.0, nan), (202106L, 126.0, nan),
 (202107L, 130.0, nan), (202108L, 133.0, nan), (202109L, 136.0, nan),
 (202110L, 139.0, nan), (202111L, 144.0, nan), (202112L, 148.0, nan),
 (202201L, 150.0, 50.0), (202202L, 152.0, 38.2), (202203L, 154.0, 33.9),
 (202204L, nan, 30.0), (202205L, nan, 25.0), (202206L, nan, 20.0)], 
          dtype=[('yyyymm', '<i8'), ('rev', '<f8'), ('yoy_pct_rev', '<f8')]))

df1.set_index('yyyymm')
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

'rev' is revenue and 'yoy_pct_rev' is the 12-month % change.  For Apr-June 2022 I have been given the growth rates and I want to forecast revenue for these 3 months.  When I use a for-loop the code works, even though my 'yyyymm' index shifts to a column:

```
for i in range(12,len(df1.index)):
    df1.iloc[i, 1] = df1.iloc[i-12, 1]*((df1.iloc[i,2]/100)+1)    
df1
```

[image]

I have multiple dataframes with the exact same columns and rows but with different rev and yoy_pct_rev values.  If I take my example from above and use a list:

```
my_list=[df1]

for i in range(12,len(my_list.index)):
    my_list.iloc[i, 0] = my_list.iloc[i-12,0]*((my_list.loc[i,1]/100)+1)                               
df1
```

I get an error: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len().

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Technically you get the error because you're trying to compute the `len` of the `index` method, not of its result - in other words you're _mentioning_ the method, not _calling_ it

Comment: So how would you modify the code so it works?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with that `index`. But for sure, it's `my_list.index(someargument)`

Comment: OK thanks...I'm not a sophisticated python coder, so how would you change the code I have above so it's using my_list.index(someargument)?